# JIT Debugging popup not coming up for processes running in session 0

Tags: debugging, windows-server-2008, jit

I set up my development environment on a widows server 2008 r2 machine. The problem is that whenever a process that is running in session 0 crashes, i get absolutely no notification of it. No Windows error reporting, no visual studio jit debugging prompt. If a regular application crashes, then i get the jit debugging popup and am able to attach the debugger fine. What could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

In W2K8 session 0 services run with no UI (non interactive). Therefore you'll never get a popup. One way around this is to set your AEDebug regkey to attach either ntsd or cdb with remote debugging, something like `ntsd.exe -server tcp:port=50000:54999 -p %ld -e %ld -g -noio`.  Then when something crashes, you will see the ntsd.exe process running in taskmgr and you can attach to it (you'll need to use cdb and query which ports are open for debugging).  This can easily be wrapped in some sort of daemon process or service that's continuously monitoring for new debugging sessions and automatically pop up cdb for you.

You can then extend this pattern to launch an arbitrary logging process instead of ntsd. Just make sure the process is running with the right permissions and no UI.